# UITableView not reloading data or calling cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am having a serious issue with `UITableView`'s `reloadData` method. I have a `UIViewController` class, `WiGiMainViewController` that has a `UITableView` and `NSMuttableArray` in it. I am currently issuing network calls in the `AppDelegate`, and posting notifications to the `WiGiMainViewController` once the data has been downloaded. In my selector method for the notification, reloadWigiList, I am passing an `NSArray` containing the the recently downloaded items. I then initialize the `WiGiMainViewController`'s `NSMuttableArray` with the passed in array and proceed to call `reloadData()` on my `UITableView` object. I can see from `NSLog` statements that the `numberOfRowsInSection` is fired on reload but not the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, therefore causing the UI NOT to reload the `UITableView` with the newly downloaded items. I have verified that the `reloadData` method is being called on the main thread and that the datasource delegate are set in `IB` and programatically in the viewDidLoad method of WiGiMainViewController. Any ideas why my `UITableView`, wigiLists isn't reloading the data, in particular, not calling the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method?

```
 @interface WiGiMainViewController :     UIViewController<FBRequestDelegate,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {

 //setup UI
 UITableView *wigiLists;

 WiGiAppDelegate *myAppDelegate;
 NSMutableArray *itemsList;

}
 @property (nonatomic, retain) WiGiAppDelegate *myAppDelegate;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *wigiLists;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *itemsList;

-(void) reloadWigiList: (NSNotification*) notification;
-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
 -(NSInteger) tableView: (UITableView*) tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger) section;
 -(UITableViewCell *) tableView: (UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:   (NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

@end


 @implementation WiGiMainViewController

 @synthesize headerLabel = _headerLabel, userNameLabel = _userNameLabel, facebookPicture = _facebookPicture,
 myAppDelegate, wigiLists, itemsList;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
 NSLog(@"In viewDidLoad");
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self   selector:@selector(reloadWigiList:) name:@"wigiItemUpdate" object:nil];


 // get appdelicate
 self.myAppDelegate = (WiGiAppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];     
 self.itemsList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 //setup tableview
  self.wigiLists = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStylePlain];
      self.wigiLists.delegate = self;
 self.wigiLists.dataSource = self;
 //set up view
 [self.headerLabel setText:self.myAppDelegate.HEADER_TEXT];
 //check if user is logged in
 if (self.myAppDelegate.isLoggedIn) {
      //user is logged in
      NSLog(@"HERE");
      //get facebook information to populate view
      [self retrieveFacebookInfoForUser];
      //[self.myAppDelegate retrieveWigiItems];
 }else {
      //user is not logged in
      NSLog(@"user not logged in");
      //show login modal
 }
 //[self.wigiLists reloadData];
 [super viewDidLoad];
}

 -(void) reloadWigiList: (NSNotification *) notification {
 if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
      NSLog(@"main thread");
 }else{
      NSLog(@"METHOD NOT CALLED ON MAIN THREAD!");
 }
 NSLog(@"notification recieved:%@", notification.userInfo);

 NSLog(@"in reloadwigilists:%@", wigiLists );
 NSLog(@"list size:%@", self.itemsList);
 NSLog(@"delegate:%@",self.wigiLists.delegate);
 NSLog(@"datasource:%@",self.wigiLists.dataSource);
 //populate previously empty itemsList
 [self.itemsList setArray:notification.userInfo];
 NSLog(@"list size:%@", self.itemsList);
 [self.wigiLists reloadData];

}

 /////////////////////////////////////
 // UITableViewDelegate protocols
 -(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
 //NSLog(@"numberofsections: %@", [self.itemsList count]);
 return 1;
}

 -(NSInteger) tableView: (UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger) section {
 NSLog(@"7t87giuiu%@",self.itemsList);
 NSLog(@"numberofrows: %i", [self.itemsList count]);


      return [self.itemsList count];

 //return 6;

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow! after 3 days of banging my head against this problem, it was something ridiculously simple. In my ViewDidLoad method of WiGiMainViewController, i was initializing my tableview:

```
self.wigiLists = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

Because I had linked the tableView I created in IB to my instance wigiLists, alloc'ing and initializing in the ViewDidLoad overwrote my link to the tableView created in IB and currently being displayed. Getting rid of this line fixed everything.

Comment: Glad to hear you fixed your question. Go ahead and accept your answer to let others know.