# UITableView reloadData not working

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch, reloaddata

I a UITableView called `tableView`. It's data array called `namesArray`.

I have a function that adds a name to the array that looks like this:

```
-(void)addName:(NSString*)name
{
    [self.namesArray addObject: name];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Note: I'm calling `addNames:` as a selector from NSNotificationCenter.

After I call `reloadData` on `tableView`, the last cell (the one that was added) is not showing on `tableView`, `numberOfRowsInSection` return the actual number so there is a space for another cell but there is not an actual cell.

I was debugging `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and I was found out that when `cellForRowAtIndexPath` called for the new cell it's all looks fine, it's seems like it's returning the correct cell so I really don't know what the problem is.

The code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text=[self.namesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

numberOfRows:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.namesArray.count;
}
```

Note: if I try to print the last object of `namesArray` using `NSLog` it's looking fine (the last object is the new one that was created) so it's a problem with reloading the data of `tableView`

screenshot after adding a new name (all the names + one place for a cell but it's blank (nto just the title, you can't even select it)):
[image: screenshot]

Can you please help me? Thanks you very much!

Comment: just try to reload a second later adding newObject

Comment: Is your namesArray an NSArray or an NSMutableArray?

Comment: @SyedAliSalman I don't understand what you mean, can you please explain more?

Comment: @gmat1014 NSMutableArray

Comment: Can you share your screenshot after adding new name. Your code looks fine.

Comment: Check that you are connected dataSource delegate.

Comment: @Yhper I am saying to try calling `[self.tableView reloadData] a second later after you have added new object in array

Comment: Is `addName:` called from main thread?

Comment: @Syed Ali Salman that is not the issue here - you don't need the delay, something else is broken. dataSource shouldn't be it either because the other cells are displaying.

Comment: my point is that it might be a reason that adding new object is not completed at back and reloading returns less

Comment: @Larme this could be it :) i Suggest you check your threads by assert([NSThread currentThread] == [NSThread mainThread]);

Comment: @Dev.RK Updated the post, please take a look

Comment: try this [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

Comment: @VineeshTP All connected

Comment: @Larme I'm calling it as a selector from NSNotificationCenter

Comment: @daredevil not working :(

Comment: @Yhper i think blank white space is your tableView background. To check just try to print indexPath.row of all cell and check last index of row is equal to nameArray.count-1

Comment: @Dev.RK It is. When I'm trying to add a name at the first time the dataSource methods(numberOfRows+cellForRow) are being called but if I try to add another name after it, the dataSource methods are not even being called.

Comment: Do you post a notification from the same class? Because the self. before tableView could not refer to this class and so does not match the table view.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363350/uitableview-not-reloading-data-or-calling-cellforrowatindexpath

Comment: @euthimis87 It's not from the same class

Comment: @Dev.RK I'm not reInitialize (tableView=[UITableVIew alloc]init) on viewDidLoad...

Comment: [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

Comment: @Dev.RK still not working :((

Comment: @Yhper try to reload tableView with other reloadData options of tableView.

Comment: @Yhper try to test purpose only, return [self.namesArray count] + 1; in numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: @Dev.RK Still not working...

Comment: @Dev.RK Which reloadData options?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           [self.tableView reloadData];
        });
```

It will call `reloadData` method on the main thread.

Comment: have you called [self.namesArray addObject: name];
also inside  the dispatch block just before reloaddata.?
If not please try once.